How can I efficiently calculate the score function gradient estimator (REINFORCE algorithm)?
I wish to use the score function gradient estimator (also called the REINFORCE algorithm). Taking the notation and equations from the first link, this allows us to estimate gradients of the expected value of a function f without having to differentiate f directly, instead using a Monte Carlo approximation and gradients of the log-pdf of some distribution p with parameters θ.


However, I am having difficulty calculating this estimator using tensorflow's automatic differentiation and distributions from tensorflow_probability.
Here is an example illustrating my problem using a small toy example. Here the probability distribution p is a standard normal, and the function f(x)=x is simply the identity.
import scipy
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

# Distribution Settings
scale = 1
mean = 0

normal_dist = scipy.stats.norm(loc=mean, scale=scale)

# Number of independent datapoints 
T = 1000

seed=360
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)
y_T = normal_dist.rvs(size=T, random_state=rng)

# create keras model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=0)
# a dense layer with an empty input will just be an intercept term
intercept_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = None)
# Create a normal distribution with a mean equal to the input 
distribution_layer = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=t, scale=1))
predicted_mean = intercept_layer(inputs)
distribution = distribution_layer(predicted_mean)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=distribution)

# Create an empty input so we can do a forward pass
x_TF = np.zeros(shape=(T,0))

# number of score function trick samples
N=50
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    model_distribution = model(x_TF)
    sample_y_NT = model_distribution.sample(N)
    sample_log_probs_NT = model_distribution.log_prob(sample_y_NT)

# use jacobian to get gradient of each sample
jacobian_params_NT = tape.jacobian(sample_log_probs_NT , model.trainable_weights)

The above code works for small N (it takes about 40 seconds for N=25), but N=50 never terminates.
I've read the documentation for the jacobian, and it recommends enclosing the function call in a @tf.function() decorator, but when I do this performance degrades even further. There's nothing terribly complex about this computation- you can analytically differentiate the logpdf of a standard normal, and it's trivial to compute these gradients for much larger number of samples, so I know the problem must be with how I'm using the GradientTape.
I'm using Keras 2., Tensorflow 2.15, and tensorflow_probability 0.23. If there's other solutions in JAX or PyTorch I'd be happy to entertain those
